# Is it possible to load specific number of data on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making chat application with Firebase Realtime Database.

I Made

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ChildEventListener{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Message msg = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    this.addItem(msg);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ...
}
```

and this `MessageAdapter` refresh my `Listview` when data is added to Firebase.

But

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Message msg = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    this.addItem(msg);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`onChildAdded` Method is called whenever I started app. I want to load Message Only after User starting app. It loads every messages which is stored in my Firebase Realtime Database.

Is there a way to load only new message after user starting application? and furthermore I want to make this to load specific number of messages like if I set the number as 5, when user start an app it loads from Firebase Database only 5 stored messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are a couple questions here, first would be to make the app wait before querying the data base. To do this I would suggest pausing the thread for a few seconds while it loads the data using a handler.

```
 handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        // Your Database Reference Listener
     }
}, 1000);
```

also to listen to only a few from firebase just change the listener like so

```
 yourDatabaseReferance.limitToFirst(10).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

Comment: If i do like yourDatabaseReferance.limitToFirst(10).addChildEventListener(this)  it doesn't load any more after initializing.. How can i do for limit 10 messages and add after that?

Comment: Oh my bad, I used limitToLast(10)